# How to make current row value equal to previous row value if a column equals a value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df

ID  val
1   0.0
2   yes
3   1.0
4   0.0
5   yes
```

How do I match the previous value with the current value if the column val equals "yes"

I tried `df['val'] = df['val'].replace('yes', np.nan).bfill().astype(str)` , but wont work as desired.

desired output

```
ID  val
1   yes
2   yes
3   1.0
4   yes
5   yes
```

can we use np.where along with bfill? how to go about with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
df.loc[df['val'].shift(-1).eq('yes'), 'val'] = 'yes'
```

Output:

```
   ID  val
0   1  yes
1   2  yes
2   3  1.0
3   4  yes
4   5  yes
```